# markdown pdf by pandoc : fontsize of 11 or 12pt grow the font, but 13 or 14pt return to a lower size

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

Using this header :

```
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fvextra}
- \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,breakanywhere,breaksymbol=,breakanywheresymbolpre=,commandchars=\\\{\}}

title: "Analyse spatiale"
subtitle: "Geostatistique, QGIS, Geoserver"
author: Marc Le Bihan
geometry: margin=2cm
fontsize: 12pt
output: pdf
classoption: fleqn
urlcolor: blue
---
```

for a markdown transformed with `pandoc` to a *pdf* with this markdown command :

`pandoc -f markdown-implicit_figures analyse_spatiale.md -o analyse_spatiale.pdf`

`11pt` or `12pt` have a visible effect in the *pdf* for `fontsize:`, but `13pt`, `14pt` return to a lower font.

Why?

Comment: 13pt and 14pt are not class options which are allowed by default. They will fall back to the default 10pt option

Comment: Have a look at https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/extsizes

Answer (score 2):

13pt and 14pt are not class options which are allowed by default. They will fall back to the default 10pt option. However you can use the `extsizes` package to make more font sizes available:

```
---
title: "Analyse spatiale"
subtitle: "Geostatistique, QGIS, Geoserver"
author: Marc Le Bihan
output: pdf_document
geometry: margin=2cm
classoption: fleqn
urlcolor: blue
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fvextra}
- \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,breakanywhere,breaksymbol=,breakanywheresymbolpre=,commandchars=\\\{\}}
- \usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
---

fff
```

Comment: I added this package, but it had the drawback that then margins were ignored. And all my text was gathering in the middle of the document (huge margins of 5 or 7 cm?)

Comment: @MarcLeBihan That's because pandoc automatically loads the geometry package. If you would have control over the preamble, you would load geometry after extsizes because extsizes already reduces the margins compared to the default article layout.

Comment: Add `- \geometry{margin=2cm}`

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with LaTeX, which pandoc uses to generate the PDF: The default LaTeX `article` class only supports 10pt, 11pt, and 12pt font sizes; any other value will be ignored.